# Python Tkinter Loop issue

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, user-interface, tkinter

Updating the GUI in a loop? Ok, I am working on a Python Tkinter project.
And am having issues with the for loop. `for i in range(15):`

---

So far I have tried
`root.update_idletasks()` and `root.config`
to update the GUI while it is in the loop. But the GUI only updates when the loop is completed.
`pyautogui.locateOnScreen` seems to be the culprit.
To cause it not to update the GUI.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't use long for or while running loops in a GUI. You have to move your code to tkinter's mainloop, or use a separate thread or process. Show us a [mcve] if you want specific help.

Answer (score 0):

To update a tkinter window, you should use the functions

```py
root.update()
root.update_idletasks()
```

Overwise, the window won't update correctly.